# ¿Cómo declarar el constructor de un objeto con atributos de tipo puntero en C++?

Tags: c++, punteros, clase, codeblocks

Tengo este diagrama UML pero no sé cómo declarar los atributos de tipo puntero en el constructor. Nunca me había encontrado con un atributo dentro de la clase como el que tiene esta. En realidad no sé cómo proceder para crear el constructor. Es el único problema que tengo porque en todo lo demás, ya lo tengo resuleto. No sé si se inicia el puntero en la clase, en el constructor o dentro del método o bien, si se tiene que hacer en la función principal. No agrego el código de las demás clases porque no me lo permite el sítio
[[image: Diagrama UML1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class Usuario
{
private:
    string Nombre, Credencial;
    int TotalPrest, RevPrest, LibPrest;
    int *L, *R;
    
public:
    Usuario(void);
    ~Usuario(void);
    Usuario (int, int);
    void GetData();
    void PintData()
    
};

//Constructor Clase Usuario
Usuario::Usuario(string _Nombre, string _Credencial, int _TotalPrest, int _RevPrest, int _LibPrest)
{
    _Nombre = Nombre;
    _Credencial = Credencial;
    _TotalPrest = TotalPrest;
    _RevPrest = RevPrest;
    _LibPrest = LibPrest;
}
Usuario::~Usuario()
{
    
}
Usuario::Usuario(int _*R, int _*L)
{
    _RevPrest = RevPrest;
    _LibPrest = LibPrest;
}
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: @Arriel, ya he agregado cambios a la pregunta con una descripción más consistente. Muchísimas gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieres almacenar un entero, declaras una variable de tipo `int`, que es un tipo de dato que almacena números enteros:

```
int variable;
```

Si en vez de un entero necesitas trabajar con cadenas de caracteres el tipo `int` ya no te servirá. Una opción en este caso sería `std::string`:

```
std::string variable;
```

Vamos a complicarlo un poco, ahora resulta que tenemos que apuntar a una lista de enteros. Como estamos apuntando necesitamos un puntero. Pero no apuntamos a cualquier cosa, en la lista hay enteros, luego la variable ahora la declararemos así:

```
int * puntero;
```

Vale, ¿Y si ahora queremos apuntar a un objeto de tipo `Revista`? Este caso es muy similar al anterior. Tenemos que apuntar a un objeto, luego necesitamos un puntero... y el objeto apuntado es de tipo `Revista` por lo que la variable habría que declararla así:

```
Revista * puntero;
```

Así de simple. Lo que tu has puesto en tu código no tiene ni pies ni cabeza:

```
Usuario::Usuario(int _*R, int _*L)
```

Por dos razones básicas:

- Ese `_` no se puede poner ahí, eso no compila.
- `R` supuestamente apunta a un objeto de tipo `Revista` y `L` a uno de tipo `Libro`

Es decir, el constructor debería quedar así:

```
Usuario::Usuario(Revista * revista, Libro * libro)
```

Nota que ese mismo engendro lo tienes al declarar las variables miembro de la clase `Usuario`, ahí también hay que corregirlo:

```
class Usuario
{
private:
    string Nombre, Credencial;
    int TotalPrest, RevPrest, LibPrest;
    int *L, *R;  // <<---
```

Ahora bien, lo esperable es que para un objeto dado, únicamente se ejecute uno de sus constructores, por lo que no parece que tenga demasiado sentido tener, como es tu caso, 2 constructores. Lo más llamativo es que el segundo constructor solo inicializaría los campos `revista` y `libro`. ¿Y qué pasa con el resto de campos?

Ahora nos vamos a mover en en el terreno de las suposiciones ya que no tengo el enunciado completo.

Yo esperaría que un usuario pudiese tener una revista y/o un libro, pero esa asociación tiene pinta de ser opcional, es decir, no existe la obligación de que esos punteros referencien un objeto válido.

Así pues quizás lo más natural sería dejar únicamente un constructor. En este constructor hay que hacer un par de arreglos:

- Las asignaciones se hacen **al revés**. Debes pasar valores de los parámetros de la función a las variables miembro, tu estás haciendo justo lo contrario:

  ```
    Usuario::Usuario(string _Nombre, string _Credencial, int _TotalPrest, int _RevPrest, int _LibPrest)
    {
        Nombre = _Nombre;
        Credencial = _Credencial;
        TotalPrest = _TotalPrest;
        RevPrest = _RevPrest;
        LibPrest = _LibPrest;
    }
  ```
- Por convención, las variables deberían empezar por minúsculas, no por mayúsculas.
- Faltan por inicializar los punteros (asumamos que al arreglar la declaración de los punteros les has cambiado el nombre):

  ```
    Usuario::Usuario(string _nombre, string _credencial, int _totalPrest, int _revPrest, int _libPrest)
    {
        nombre = _Nombre;
        credencial = _credencial;
        totalPrest = _totalPrest;
        revPrest = _revPrest;
        libPrest = _libPrest;
        revista = nullptr;
        libro = nullptr;
    }
  ```
- En los constructores, es preferible inicializar las variables de esta otra forma:

  ```
    Usuario::Usuario(string _nombre, string _credencial, int _totalPrest, int _revPrest, int _libPrest)
        : nombre{_nombre}
        , credencial{_credencial}
        , totalPrest{_totalPrest}
        , revPrest{_revPrest}
        , libPrest{_libPrest}
        , revista{nullptr}
        , libro{nullptr}
    }
  ```

Ahora solo faltaría declarar un par de métodos para poder actualizar los punteros de `Revista` y de `Libro`:

```
class Usuario
{
public:

    void SetRevista(Revista* revista)
    {
        this->revista = revista;
    }

    void SetLibro(Libro* libro)
    {
        this->libro = libro;
    }
};
```